# Why doesn't setw(n) work here?

Tags: c++, setw

Here is my problem:

> Given  three variables, a, b, c, of type double that have already been declared  and initialized, write some code that prints each of them in a 15 position field on the same line, in such away that scientific (or e-notation or exponential notation) is avoided. Each number should be printed with 5 digits to the right of the decimal point. For example, if their values  were 24.014268319, 14309, 0.00937608, the output  would be:
>
> |xxxxxxx24.01427xxxx14309.00000xxxxxxxx0.00938
>
> NOTE: The vertical bar, | , on the left above represents the left edge of the print area; it is not to be printed out. Also, we show x in the output  above to represent spaces-- your output  should not actually have x's!

Here is in essence what I'm trying to do:

`cout << fixed << setprecision(5) << 24.014268319 << setw(5) << 5252.25151516 << endl;`

But this produces the following output:

`24.014275252.25152`

Clearly I'm not interpreting how to use `setw(n)` properly, does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What output are you expecting? The second number your are sending to `cout` is not in the problem statement and you're outputting a space between the first and second numbers.

Comment: shouldn't you say `setw(15)` instead?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious the numbers produced are random, so I just provided a random number.  I'm expecting `24.01427     5252.25152`

Comment: @rodrigo, that fixed my problem, but why doesn't `setw(5)` provide any spaces between the numbers?

Comment: Try using `setw(15)` before the first number.

Comment: `setw()` determines how much space the number should take up (at least, so if you print 10010191001121.1234, then it may well take up more - and thus not give you any space between.

Comment: No, `setw(5)` will extend the width used by the next number up to 5 characters, but given that it uses about 10 by itself, it does nothing useful. If you want a space then just `<< ' '`.

Comment: @rodrigo got it, thank you!  I'm new to c++, obviously haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `setw(...)` I/O manipulator is a little tricky, in that its effect is being reset, i.e. the width is set back to zero, after each call of `<<` (among other things described in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)).

You need to call `setw(15)` multiple times, like this:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(5) << setw(15) << 24.014268319  << setw(15) << 5252.25151516 << endl;
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/9E71ot)